# MySQL - Multiple column UPDATE statement using IF statements

Tags: mysql

The goal is to link table 1 to table 2 and populate table 1 when table 1 is not the default value.

Example:

```
UPDATE table1 aa, table2 bb
SET aa.column2=IF(aa.column2=0,bb.column2,aa.column2) and aa.column3=IF(aa.column3=0,bb.column3,aa.column3)... Total of 5 columns being updated
WHERE aa.column1=bb.column1;
```

When running this I receive poor population.  However, if I remove all but one IF statement from the SET line everything works as intended.

I'm rather new to MySQL so any help that anyone could provide would be greatly appreciate.

Comment: "poor population"? What do you actually get?

Comment: Andrew - By poor population I'm referring to columns that were not populated as they should've been (assuming my statement was written correctly).  For example, I found several control rows that I verified had a unique join between the two tables.  Using the statement above several of my control rows where not populated. However, by removing all but one column from my SET statement the control rows would populate. By removing AND and placing a comma so far I've received the results I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to use explicit `join` syntax.  But, more importantly, you don't use `and` to connect `set` statements.  You use `and` to connect booleans and `,` for `set` statements.  This has a big effect on how the query is interpreted.

Try this:

```
UPDATE table1 aa JOIN
       table2 bb
       ON aa.column1=bb.column1
  SET aa.column2=IF(aa.column2=0,bb.column2,aa.column2), 
      aa.column3=IF(aa.column3=0,bb.column3,aa.column3),
       ... Total of 5 columns being updated;
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.  The logic makes sense.  I'll test it on a couple queries and hopefully it will provide more consistent results.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Use comma instead `and`.
Comma is delimiter, `and` is just operator.